# Check if a string contains a specific number of given values

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm

I am trying to decode a message provided as a morse code via command line argument. If the provided string contains 7 spaces it means that I need to print a space to the decoded string.
This is the way I am trying to check if string contains 7 spaces via for loop:

```
                if ((str[i] == ' ' && str[i + 1] == ' ' &&
                 str[i + 2] == ' ' && str[i + 3] == ' ' &&
                 str[i + 4] == ' ' && str[i + 5] == ' ' &&
                 str[i + 6] == ' ')) {
                mx_printchar(' ');
               }
```

Please let me know if any efficient way could be used for this purpose.
Currently, I cannot use linked lists or structs, but maybe there is any other way, please advise

Comment: Take a look at `strstr`. Or something like  `memcmp(&str[i], "       ", 7)`. (there are 7 spaces in there if not displayed clearly...)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `substr()` instead as shown below :

```
if (str.substr(i,7) == "       ") {
     //do your task here
}
```

This will check for the substring from `i` to `i+7`(this index included) and if this substring is equal to 7 spaces, then it will do the required task.